# Swift: Populating Information from a Data File

Tags: macos, swift

I'm new to Swift and programming in general.

I'm working on a small OSX application that displays information for countries when the user clicks on a map of the world.  The map interface works fine.  I've tried this on a smaller map with just four countries. I've put my country data into a class called Country with variables for the data (e.g. population, landArea, majorExport, etc.)  I put the Countries into an array.  When the user selects a country, the controller grabs the right Country from the array and populates the data fields.  So far, so good.

I'm getting ready to scale up to a map of the world with 150+ countries.  Is there a way to store all of my data in a separate file (like a .csv file) so I don't have to hard code all of this Country data directly in a .swift file?  If so:
(a) what kind of file should I use?
(b) how would I set it up?
(c) how do I get the application access it?

Thank you.

Comment: Aren’t there any API’s from which you can get this data? that way you would not have to store it.

Comment: I'm customizing some of the data, so I have to store at least some of it.

Comment: I recommend an XML file, it's the most common thing to do and there are a lot of great API's to handle XML files

Comment: @Kametrixom JSON would be easier than xml. This doesnt seem like it would require anything more than an array of dictionaries basically.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I think about it, you can use a .plist file. It's the easiest, because you can simple use `dict.writeToFile:` to write and `NSDictionary(contentsOfFile:)` to read. And since NSDictionary is bridged to Swift, it just works. I found [this](http://rebeloper.com/read-write-plist-file-swift/) great article